# What kind of construct would use the comment delimiter */ in a Javascript?

Tags: javascript, comments

From ["Javascript: the Good Parts": the Good Parts](http://bluebones.net/2011/04/javascript-the-good-parts-the-good-parts/):

> Avoid `/* … */` for comments, `*/` appears in useful constructs in javascript. Use `//`.

I'm curious as to what these "useful constructs" might be, as I can't think of any OTOH (except maybe a regex like `/.*/`?)

Comment: Regex literal and string literal.

Comment: One would hope, but then one would be disappointed.

Comment: If that were the case, then if you always use the RegExp constructor, you can safely use `/*…*/` for comments.

Comment: @user1689607: Yeesh, that is kind of nasty. That's a reasonable answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blogger was trying to abbreviate what Crockford wrote at JavaScript: The Good Parts, Chapter number 2 ( Grammar ). This topic comes on the last paragraph of the first section ( Whitespace ). It says,

> The  /* */ form  of  block  comments  came  from  a  language  called 
>   PL/I.  PL/I  chose  those strange pairs as the symbols for comments
>   because they were unlikely to occur  in  that  language’s  programs, 
>   except  perhaps  in  string  literals.  In  JavaScript,  those  pairs
>   can also occur in regular expression literals, so block comments are
>   not safe for  commenting out blocks of code. For example:
>
> ```
>  /* 
>      var rm_a = /a*/.match(s); 
>  */
> ```
>
> causes a syntax error. So, it is recommended that /* */ comments be
>   avoided and //  comments be used instead. In this book, // will be
>   used exclusively.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, regular expressions are most likely what he was referring to.